# ocaml convert string UTF8 to CP1251

Tags: encoding, ocaml

Help me write correct code, I need convert string from utf8 to cp1251. Using the library Uutf.

my code is not work

```
let str = "русский текст" in
let decode = Uutf.encoding_of_string str in
Uutf.encoding_to_string decode;;
```

I found another solution. Convert string via library Tk.

```
open Tk;;
let top = openTk ();;
let str = "abracadabra" in
let x = Encoding.convertfrom ~encoding:"utf-8" abracadabra in
print_endline(x);;
```

Comment: You say you want to use `BatUTF8`, but your code uses `Uutf`. What library do you want to use ?

Comment: The Vg PDF renderer has code to translate Unicode scalar values to CP1251. See [here](https://github.com/dbuenzli/vg/blob/a100b5b1b382229ab42e60b62330abe70c4aaa7c/src/vgr_pdf.ml#L376-L393)

Comment: Oops sorry the linked code is for CP1252, but using [this link](http://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/WINDOWS/CP1251.TXT) and the code it should be a straightfoward exercise.

Comment: thanks this is good, but how i get 2 byte from my string and convert to int   `let uchar_to_cp1252 =
  [ 0x20AC, 0x80; 0x201A, 0x82; 0x0192, 0x83; 0x201E, 0x84; 0x2026, 0x85;
    0x2020, 0x86; 0x2021, 0x87; 0x02C6, 0x88; 0x2030, 0x89; 0x0160, 0x8A;
    0x2039, 0x8B; 0x0152, 0x8C; 0x017D, 0x8E; 0x2018, 0x91; 0x2019, 0x92;
    0x201C, 0x93; 0x201D, 0x94; 0x2022, 0x95; 0x2013, 0x96; 0x2014, 0x97;
    0x02DC, 0x98; 0x2122, 0x99; 0x0161, 0x9A; 0x203A, 0x9B; 0x0153, 0x9C;
    0x017E, 0x9E; 0x0178, 0x9F; ];;` 
`print_char(char_of_int(List.assoc 2byte uchar_to_cp1252));;`

Comment: You can use `Uutf.String.fold_utf_8` to fold over the Unicode scalar values of an UTF-8 encoded string.

Comment: Thanks, I found another solution. Convert string via library Tk.

Answer (score 2):

Neither Batteries Included nor Uutf handles the CP1251 encoding, as far as I can tell. You might look at [Camomile](https://github.com/yoriyuki/Camomile).

(It's interesting to ask yourself what encoding is being used in the quoted text of your source code.)

Comment: I tried Camomile, but after when compiling generate an error file "camomile.a" not found

Comment: If things compiled OK you probably have everything you need. You just need to tell the compiler what libraries to use. Details depend on what your development environment looks like.